# An integration theory puzzle

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, definite-integrals

I'm rather new to calculus theory and I ran into the following puzzling question:

Suppose we ran a binary classifier on a set of observations. We then plotted the True Positive Rate (TPR) over the False Positive rate (1-Specificity) for a continuous threshold varying from 1 to 0, i.e an ROC plot.

We have two distributions of observations classfier ratings:

> 1. Classifier ratings for real positive observations $X_1$ with pdf $p_1(x)$
> 2. Classifier ratings for real negative observations $X_0$ with pdf $p_0(x)$

> - The threshold for rating is $\theta$
> - Observation's rating X, if $X>\theta$ is classified positive, regardless of it's actual world state.
> - Observation's rating X, if  $X\leq\theta$ is classified as negative the same way.

the integration for a binary classifier ROC curve is very straightforward:

> $$(a).\int_1^0P(X_1>\theta)d(X_0>\theta)$$
> or
> $$(b).\int_1^0[TPR]d[1-Specificity]$$

However I ran into this integration for the integrand of equasion (a) or TPR:

> $$(c).  P(X_1>\theta) = \int_\theta^1p_1(x)dx$$
> and we know for pdf's
> $$(d).\int_\theta^1p_1(x)dx = P(\theta\leq x \leq 1)$$

The problem I find in equasion (c) is that the interval includes $\theta$ since integration intervals are closed. So if we have observations rated exactly $\theta$, they will be included in this integration of the probability density of the  **True Positives**, although they will be rated **negatively** (equal to threshold).

When I asked someone with stronger math background, he told me that this integration is correct because inclusivity is irrelevant in integrals of continuous spaces since $P(X=x)=0$.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#Curves_in_ROC_space) was also in line with this view.

I thought the integration in equation (c) should be

$$P(X_1>\theta) = 1-\int_0^\theta p_1(x)dx$$

I believe the $P(X=x)=0$ is relevant for a given pdf of a specific distribution. For a given distribution with a given pdf you can omit a finit number of points from the interval and the integral will remain the same. However a distribution that includes observations that equal exactly $\theta$ has a different pdf than a distribution that does not have exactly $\theta$ rated observations, and thus such a distribution has a different integral.

Am I missing something?